# CSS - margin and float property

Tags: css

1. We have a div with static positioning. Inside we have a paragraph with a margin. 
   The height of the div will be the paragraph without the margin
2. We have a div with float:left. Inside we have a paragraph with a margin. The height of the div will be the paragraph plus its margin.

What is the explanation of this?

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="nivel1">
<div id="nivel21">
    <p>Este es el primer parrafo</p>
</div>
<div id="nivel22">
    <p>Este es el primer parrafo</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And the CSS code:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#nivel1 {
    border:solid;
    border-color:#333;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#0F3;
    margin:2em; 
}

#nivel21 {
    margin:2em;
    float:left;
    background-color:#C00;

}

#nivel22 {
    margin:2em;
    background-color:#FC0;
}
```

And here is a [link](http://prueba.davidcasillas.es/) to the test site.

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The Question is: why changing the div from static to float changes the way it calcultes its height. I'm just trying to understand by experimenting the positioning and layout things. Sorry if i make not it clear in my post.

Comment: I am observing this exact behavior in my development and I would also like to find out what's going on here. Surprising to me this question hasn't gotten a solid answer in 1 year, feels like a very generic and well-known issue.

Answer (score 1):

**After several edits, I think I have got the answer now :)**

I have also experienced this puzzling behaviour. I think part of the explanation is in [section 10.6.7 of the CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#block-root-margin):

> In certain cases (see, e.g., sections 10.6.4 and 10.6.6 above), the height of an element
> that establishes a block formatting context is computed as follows:
>
> If it only has inline-level children, the height is the distance between the top of the
> topmost line box and the bottom of the bottommost line box.
>
> If it has block-level children, the height is the distance between the top margin-edge of
> the topmost block-level child box and the bottom margin-edge of the bottommost block-
> level child box.

Those "certain cases" listed in section 10.6.6 include floating elements.

The `#nivel21` element in the question is a floating element, and it contains block-level children (a `<p>`), therefore this special-case rule is applied and the height of the `<div>` is calculated using the top and bottom margin-edges of the `<p>` tag.

Secondly, [this page about collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) may give a clue as to why the height of `#nivel22` does *not* include the margins of the `<p>` tag:

> The [...] margin-top on the p element effectively becomes the top margin of the div element, and pushes the div down the page [...]

The `<p>` tag has an implicit margin (10px in my tests), which needs to collapse with the 2em margin of the outer `#nivel1` element, so for this reason the browser pretends that the `<p>` tag has no margin at all (it puts it on `#nivel22` instead), which means that the height of `#nivel22` shrinks down to the line-height of the `<p>` tag.

I hope this answer makes sense to someone other than me!

Answer (score 0):

I think When you use the float property the browser pads the element to show is floating.

Comment: What you mean with "pads the element"?
What exectly seems to happen is that the floated div calculates its heigth (as you can see by the background color) as the inner parragraph plus its margin, while the non floated div just the parragraph without its margin. There is no padding here.

Comment: what I meant was some the browser may be internally increasing the top and bottom padding to visually show that the element is floating and is not inline with others, But I am just shooting in the dark :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there is no question and no clear naming of your elements i'll just assume you want to put 2 columns in a container.
Cleaned up code with some more clear naming and use of classes results in this:
(hope this is what you were looking for)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>divs</title>
    <style>
      .container{
      float: left;
        background-color: #0F3;
      }
      .column {
        margin: 2em;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      #lefty{
        background-color: #C00;
      }
      #righty{
        background-color: #FC0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="lefty" class="column">
        <p>Column number 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="righty" class="column">
        <p>Column number 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry I did not explain myself clearly.
I'm just experimenting to learn the CSS properties. I discovered that when I switched a div from static to floated it changed the way its heigth was calculated, so I just made a test page with two equal div , just one static and one floated to study the diferent behaviours. I know now clearly what is happening with Safari Web Insector, the floated div adds to its heigth the inner parragraph plus its margin, while the static one don't adds the inner parragraph margin. Why this happens?

Comment: I think you misunderstand margins. A margin is added to the outside of a box, increasing it's distance from it's parant or siblings. Padding is a sort of inner margin, increasing the distance it's children have from it's borders.
So, the question really is why the red one is bigger, not why the yellow one is smaller ;)

Comment: Ok, now that we have a good question, would be nice to hear an answer if any of you can give an explanation. Anyway thanks, and I will try to be more precise next time.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens because of the interaction of the two divs**. Remove the floating one, the static one will shrink. What happens is, the floating div pushes the text in the static div down, thus expanding it.

More comments: The paragraph tag is irrelevant here. You can achieve the same effect by removing the paragraph margin and increasing the margin for the elements themselves. Either way, the statically positioned element would grow while the floating one would not.  Same thing with this CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

#nivel1 {
    border:solid;
    border-color:#333;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#0F3;
    margin:2em; 
}

#nivel21 {
    margin:5em;
    float:left;
    background-color:#C00;

}

#nivel22 {
    margin:5em;
    background-color:#FC0;
```

}

Comment: There is a `}` hanging at the bottom of your answer.